# how do I assign a value of a variable to another variable

Tags: python

I am creating a game in python called "doodle war." The game isn't done. I need to assign a value of a variable to another variable. But I can't.

```
import random

print("welcome to the game of doodle war.")
print("this is how we play doodle war.\nWe will have two players, player 1 and player 2.\nYou will be given to write a name for your player.\nThen you will be given to write 6 names for your attacks.\nThen the computer will give a random number and you need to apply that number to your attack name.\nThen you and the second player will fight.\nYou and player 2 will have 100 health if one will lose all of its health they will lose.\n\n")

def doodle(p1h, p2h):
    p1 = input("Player 1, enter your name: ")
    p2 = input("Player 2, enter your name: ")
    p1a1 = input("Player 1, enter your 1st attack name: ")
    p1a2 = input("Player 1, enter your 2nd attack name: ")
    p1a3 = input("Player 1, enter your 3rd attack name: ")
    p1a4 = input("Player 1, enter your 4th attack name: ")
    p1a5 = input("Player 1, enter your 5th attack name: ")
    p1a6 = input("Player 1, enter your 6th attack name: ")

    p2a1 = input("\nPlayer 2, enter your 1st attack name: ")
    p2a2 = input("Player 2, enter your 2nd attack name: ")
    p2a3 = input("Player 2, enter your 3rd attack name: ")
    p2a4 = input("Player 2, enter your 4th attack name: ")
    p2a5 = input("Player 2, enter your 5th attack name: ")
    p2a6 = input("Player 2, enter your 6th attack name: ")


    print(random.randint(1, 12))
    p1an1 = int(input("Player 1, please enter the given number to your attack 1st name: "))
    print(random.randint(1, 12))
    p2an1 = int(input("Player 2, please enter the given number to your attack 1st name: "))
    print(random.randint(1, 12))
    p1an2 = int(input("Player 1, please enter the given number to your attack 2nd name: "))
    print(random.randint(1, 12))
    p2an2 = int(input("Player 2, please enter the given number to your attack 2nd name: "))   
    print(random.randint(1, 12))
    p1an3 = int(input("Player 1, please enter the given number to your attack 3rd name: "))
    print(random.randint(1, 12))
    p2an3 = int(input("Player 2, please enter the given number to your attack 3rd name: "))
    print(random.randint(1, 12))
    p1an4 = int(input("Player 1, please enter the given number to your attack 4th name: "))
    print(random.randint(1, 12))
    p2an4 = int(input("Player 2, please enter the given number to your attack 4th name: "))
    print(random.randint(1, 12))
    p1an5 = int(input("Player 1, please enter the given number to your attack 5th name: "))
    print(random.randint(1, 12))
    p2an5 = int(input("Player 2, please enter the given number to your attack 5th name: "))
    print(random.randint(1, 12))
    p1an6 = int(input("Player 1, please enter the given number to your attack 6th name: "))
    print(random.randint(1, 12))
    p2an6 = int(input("Player 2, please enter the given number to your attack 6th name: "))
    p1an1 = p1a1
    p1an2 = p1a2
    p1an3 = p1a3
    p1an4 = p1a4
    p1an6 = p1a5
    p1an6 = p1a6

    p2an1 = p2a1
    p2an2 = p2a2
    p2an3 = p2a3
    p2an4 = p2a4
    p2an5 = p2a5
    p2an6 = p2a6
    print(p1a1, p1a2, p1a3, p1a4, p1a5, p1a6)
    print(p2a1, p2a2, p2a3, p2a4, p2a5, p2a6)



p1h = 100
p2h = 100
doodle(p1h, p2h,)
```

I expected that the values of p1an1, p2an1 and others will be assign to p1a1, p2a1 and others . Instead
it gave the value I originally gave to p1a1, p2a1 and others

Comment: Adding numbers to variables is almost always a bad idea and on top of that using single letter variable names makes this entirely unreadable. Use dicts and arrays / lists (and then loops) instead of numbered variables.

Comment: Please provide a [*minimal* reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Because your variable names are so bad (and you apparently don't use a proper IDE) you did not realize that you never actually use `p1an1`, you assign to it twice and never read from it. Why do you expect `p1an1` to be different from `p1a1` after you literally have `p1an1 = p1a1`!? Voting to close as typo because that is what it basically is.

Comment: @luk2302: I'm guessing they were reading the assignment in the wrong direction, `foo = bar` was read as "take value of `foo` and set it to `bar`"

Answer (score 0):

So I have figured it out. So let's take p1an1 I just have to create another variable.
That's all I need. I didn't need to assign a value of a variable to another variable.